# Running script using docker run results in permission denied

Tags: macos, docker, ubuntu, permissions, dockerfile

I'm trying to run a docker image from dockerfile that I create.

the command:

```
docker build -t mytest .
docker run -v $(pwd):/main -p 8080:8080 -w /main mytest ./scripts/test.sh
```

my structure:

```
- test_folder
-- scripts
--- test.sh
```

my dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update
EXPOSE 8080
```

The error:

```
docker run -v $(pwd):/main -p 8080:8080 -w /main mytest ./scripts/test.sh
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"./scripts/test.sh\": permission denied": unknown.
```

Someone know what is wrong?

Comment: Do you copy your `test.sh` script to the container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`script.sh` doesn't have the access permissions set that are needed for execution. The following `docker run` statement will set the correct permissions.

```
docker run -v $(pwd):/main -p 8080:8080 -w /main mytest chmod +x ./scripts/test.sh && ./scripts/test.sh
```

---

You can also just execute `chmod +x ./scripts/test.sh` on your host system once and then use the `docker run` statement that you have provided in your question.